# Scatter plot with y being categorical and x being a list of sets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a plot where y-axis is categorical e.g

```
classes = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

and x-axis is the list of numbers

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Now each number can have a corresponding set

```
dic = 
    {
    1: {"A", "B"},
    2: {"D"},
    3: {"C", "D", "E"},
    4: {},
    ...
    }
```

For each number I want to plot a scatter-dot for corresponding class if present.
Something like this.
How do I achieve it with matplotlib?

I tried bunch of this, for example:

```
plt.scatter(x=dic, y=classes)
plt.show()
```

But it does not work with error
ValueError: x and y must be the same size

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list of points to use the scatterplot. One liner is below.

```
x, y = list(zip(*[[a, b] for a in dic for b in dic[a]]))
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a `for` loop:

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    plt.scatter([k]*len(v),list(v))
    
plt.yticks(classes)
plt.xticks(nums)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the order of y-axis is not important, then the below code should do the trick -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {
    1: {"A", "B"},
    2: {"D"},
    3: {"C", "D", "E"},
    4: {}
}

x_values = []
y_values = []

for key in dic:
    for value in dic[key]:
        x_values.append(key)
        y_values.append(value)

print(x_values)
print(y_values)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values)

plt.show()
```

This would result in the following graph -

[image]